# Can't see my wanted level

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

I have an original copy of GTA 5 for PC. After the 3rd update (325 MB) I cannot see my wanted level anymore. Also, during the loading screen, it shows Xbox controls on the right bottom of the screen (the splash screen). Are there any fixes to this? If not, is there any way to perform a master reset on my settings?

Comment: Try verifying the integrity of the game crash. If any files are messed up, this should fix them.

Comment: Also make sure that the game isn't set to display beyond the edges of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and make sure that HUD is turned on, I had the problem where if I pressed <kbd>z</kbd>, it would not show my money and it also wasn't showing the wanted level. It works now that HUD is on.